# Symbolicate crash dumps after stripping static library

Tags: ios, debug-symbols

We ship static libraries for iOS. These are stripped with `-SxX` to a) cut down the file size and b) provide a little obfuscation.

However, there does not seem to be a way to retain the mapping from `__lldb_unnamed_functionXXXXX$$BundleName` to the original symbol, so crash reports we receive are pretty useless. The `strip` that comes with xcode doesn't have the options that GNU's version has to give you a file you can re-combine with the .a to restore the symbols, and dSYM files aren't generated for libraries.

Are there any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

No there is no other way than shipping with the symbols and *NOT* stripping them.